# error: can't find crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/kenpratt/jvm-assembler).
But, `cargo build` says this:

```
   Compiling test v0.1.0 (file:///C:/path/to/project/test)
src\main.rs:1:1: 1:28 error: can't find crate for `jvm_assembler` [E0463]
src\main.rs:1 extern crate jvm_assembler;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `test`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

My `Cargo.toml` is this:

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["yomizu_rai"]

[dependencies]
jvm-assembler = "*"
```

`src/main.rs` is this, and there are no other sourcefiles.

```
extern crate jvm_assembler;
use jvm_assembler::*;
fn main() {}
```

I think my `Cargo.toml` is not wrong, and `src/main.rs` has no room for mistake.
Why can not rustc find jvm-assembler?
How do I resolve?

Comment: have you tried naming the dependency `jvm_assembler` instead of `jvm-assembler` ?

Comment: yes, and cargo says `no matching package named 'jvm_assembler' found (required by 'test')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cargo can only find crates by name if they are on crates.io. In your case you need to specify the git URL, see the [section on dependencies](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-dependencies-section) in the Cargo documentation.

Comment: To expand on this: There is a `jvm_assembler` crate on crates.io, but that seems to only contain an executable, not the library (probably because `jvm-assembler`'s `Cargo.toml` doesn't have `exe` and `lib` sections).

Comment: Thank you!  Adding git URL to Cargo.toml, it goes well.